# Windows 10 перенаправить исходящий трафик на другой IP

Tags: windows, iptables, netsh

На компе с win10 есть софт что скачивает с сервера 10.10.10.10 файлы.
Мне нужно что бы запросы приходили на сервер 195.195.195.195 где тоже есть нужные файлы.
IP адрес в софте захардкожен, доступа к исходникам нету.

Решение для linux:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 195.195.195.195:80
```

Нужно получить тот же результат в win10.

Пытался сделать так но не работает:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=10.10.10.10 connectport=80 connectaddress=195.195.195.195
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать софт сторонний для этого. К примеру http://www.tmeter.ru/
Там поменять десты исходного трафика

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]